# javascript prototype constructor syntax 1 vs syntax 2

Tags: javascript

I have seen 2 syntax for javascript prototype : first is from tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp second is generated by typescript http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

What's the advantage of second syntax over first simpler and traditional constructor syntax ?

https://jsfiddle.net/v6gxe7wc/1/

```
    function Person1(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
}

var Person2 = (function () {

  function Person2(first, last) {

    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
  }

  return Person2;
})();

var person1 = new Person1("John", "Doe");
var person2 = new Person2("John", "Doe");
```

Comment: It's not the same question : the other question is about literal object, I don't have literal syntax here.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. If you look at this line:

```
var person1 = new person1("John", "Doe");
```

...you have `new person1`, but there is no identifier named `person1`. There is, however, a `Person1`:

```
var person1 = new Person1("John", "Doe");
```

The second syntax, by the way, offers no advantages as is. Where it *would* be advantageous is if you had additional variables used by the constructor that you don't want to expose:

```
var Person2 = (function () {

  var defaultFirstName = 'John';
  var defaultLastName = 'Doe';

  function Person2(first, last) {

    this.firstName = first || defaultFirstName;
    this.lastName = last || defaultLastName;
  }

  return Person2;
})();
```

In this case, for example, `defaultFirstName` and `defaultLastName` are hidden from everything but the constructor.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll fix it but my main question remains unanswered :)